# Class not found error in Modules.php: Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

My project use Codeigniter 2.1.4(HMVC) and all of the sudden I am getting following error while calling any controller:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Fb_function' not found in
>   /var/www/html/FB_W/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php on line 105

And the line has following code:

```
$controller = ucfirst($class);  
self::$registry[$alias] = new $controller($params);
```

I have not done any changes in this file and the code so working fine from last 4 years.

how do I fix this problem?

Comment: did your server change php version?

Comment: No @Vickel. Do I need to upgrade PHP version? Currently its PHP 5.4.39

Comment: Well first of all do not assume that nothing has changed. Something has changed or else you wouldn't be seeing this "new" behaviour. The second thing to do is check if you can find that class and go from there. Without any further information that is all I can suggest.

Comment: did you check around " Class 'Fb_function' not found "?